Panel Plugin missing after installing xfce4 Screenshooter
For some reason I do not see the option to add the Screenshooter plugin in the menu where you add new items.
I am new to xfce, customizing Linux, and to Linux in general.
I decided to try out the xfce desktop environment.
Initially I ran apt install xfce4-goodies and got all those applications.
At this point the panel plugin worked without issues.
I saw that there was a newer version of Screenshooter available but not through apt. (I wanted the custom action feature)
I ran sudo apt purge xfce4-screenshooter (maybe I shouldn't have?)
Then I unpacked the tarball and went through the installation process for Screenshooter 1.10.5 as listed in the README.
I did this all in the downloads directory.
Should I have moved the panel-plugin folder into another directory manually?
Otherwise the application works great (the script for qr codes in the docs didn't work but ChatGPT wrote a working version).
